# Urxvt: change background color on the fly

Tags: colors, rxvt

Is there away to change the background color of a rxvt-unicode session on the fly? Like with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?

I have a bunch of Urxvt windows and I would like to color some dynamically to help me distinguish them. But again, I mean on the fly...

Comment: No. You can with [Termite](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Termite), though...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`urxvt` 2.6 in 2004 added support for xterm's *dynamic colors* feature.  In [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls), this is `OSC` 11.  `OSC` 10 sets the default text color.  The changelog mentioned part of the change:

```
2.6  Fri Apr  2 03:24:10 CEST 2004
        - minor doc corrections.
        - WARNING: changed menu sequence from ESC ] 10 to ESC ] 703 to
          avoid clashes with xterm.
        - changed OSC701/OSC702 sequence to return standard escaped reports.
        - xterm-compat: make set window colour and other requests report
          window colour when arg is "?".
```

but the source-code tells the story, as usual:

```
 /*
  * XTerm escape sequences: ESC ] Ps;Pt (ST|BEL)
  *       0 = change iconName/title  
  *       1 = change iconName
  *       2 = change title
  *       4 = change color
+ *      10 = change fg color 
+ *      11 = change bg color 
  *      12 = change text color
  *      13 = change mouse foreground color
  *      17 = change highlight character colour
@@ -2949,20 +3236,21 @@ 
  *      50 = change font
  *
  * rxvt extensions:
- *      10 = menu (may change in future) 
  *      20 = bg pixmap
  *      39 = change default fg color
  *      49 = change default bg color
  *      55 = dump scrollback buffer and all of screen
  *     701 = change locale
  *     702 = find font
+ *     703 = menu 
  */
```

The manual [`rxvt(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/urxvt) gives no useful information:

```
   XTerm Operating System Commands
       "ESC ] Ps;Pt ST"
           Set XTerm Parameters. 8-bit ST: 0x9c, 7-bit ST sequence: ESC \
           (0x1b, 0x5c), backwards compatible terminator BEL (0x07) is also
           accepted. any octet can be escaped by prefixing it with SYN (0x16,
           ^V).
```

This simple example sets both foreground (text) and background **default** colors:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033]10;red\007'
printf '\033]11;green\007'
```

Like `xterm`, these *default* colors can be overridden temporarily by "ANSI" colors.

The feature can be disabled in `xterm` using the **`dynamicColors`** resource.  Unlike `xterm`, `urxvt` has no resource-setting for the feature.

VTE also implements the feature, and likewise doesn't document it.  `urxvt` at least *started* with documentation from `rxvt`.  For VTE, you have to read the source code.  The relevant feature in `vteseq.cc` looks like this:

```
/* Change the default background cursor, BEL terminated */
static void
vte_sequence_handler_change_background_color_bel (VteTerminalPrivate *that, GValueArray *params)
{
        vte_sequence_handler_change_special_color_internal (that, params,
                                                            VTE_DEFAULT_BG, -1, 11, BEL);
}

/* Change the default background cursor, ST terminated */
static void
vte_sequence_handler_change_background_color_st (VteTerminalPrivate *that, GValueArray *params)
{
        vte_sequence_handler_change_special_color_internal (that, params,
                                                            VTE_DEFAULT_BG, -1, 11, ST);
}
```

That code dates back to sometime in 2003 (when it was written in C):

```
commit f39e281529827f68fd0e9bba41785d66a21efc1c
Author: Nalin Dahyabhai <nalin@src.gnome.org>
Date:   Wed Jan 22 21:35:22 2003 +0000

    accept OSC{number};{string}ST as set-text-parameters, per XTerm docs (part

    * src/caps.c: accept OSC{number};{string}ST as set-text-parameters, per XTerm
        docs (part of #104154).
    * src/keymap.c: revert change to prepend "1;" to keys with modifiers (#104139).
```

Further reading:

- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) (xterm FAQ)

Comment: I haven't tried this but this is so impressive and hard to find I will make it accepted! I hope it works in URXVT.

Comment: I tested it last night with urxvt 9.15 on my Debian 7 (to be certain that I was reading the source correctly).

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on this and say that it works like a dream. Thanks again as this info would be hard to find.

Comment: Finally I can change URxvt border color with `printf '\x9d708;black\x9c'`. Yes, I live dangerously and use 8-bit control characters. Thomas, thank you again, I always learn a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 11):

I added the following to my `~/.Xresources` file to change to colors on the fly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd>.

```
! change to red background
URxvt.keysym.C-7: command:\033]11;#ff0000\007

! change to light background
URxvt.keysym.C-8: command:\033]11;#ffffff\007

! change to dark gray background
URxvt.keysym.C-9: command:\033]11;#777777\007
```

If you want to set foreground and background color at the same time, just concatenate the commands (some colors are defined by names):

```
! change to red background
URxvt.keysym.C-7: command:\033]11;#ff0000\007\033]10;yellow\007
```

You can test your colors with a simple `echo` command, like this one:

```
echo -e '\033]11;#ff0000\007\033]10;yellow\007'   # changes to red background and yellow foreground
```

### Attention

I used code **11 for background** color and code **10 for foreground** color. The definitions for Urxvt cited by [Thomas Dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295520/31673) indicate to use **49 and 39** instead (which I tested and also work).

Comment: Now `rxvt.h` says that codes 39 and 49 (Rxvt_restoreFG and Rxvt_restoreBG) are deprecated, so 10 and 11 are the right choice.

Answer (score 4):

[Dynamic Colors](https://github.com/sos4nt/dynamic-colors) is an example of dynamically switching colors. 
It begins with using these two .Xresources:

```
xterm*dynamicColors: true
urxvt*dynamicColors: on
```

In spite of the lead, I have not gotten color changing working with urxvt though! This technique works great with xterm. Dynamic Colors calls these "OSC escape sequences" that alter the terminal. 
The example to make the background red is: `echo -e "\033]11;#ff0000\007"`.

Comment: For me the color of the background changes to red if I put this in the command line: `echo -e "\033]11;#ff0000\007"`

Answer (score 4):

I have the following in my Xresources for quick switching (yes, it's based on dynamic colors).

```
URxvt*keysym.Control-Shift-F10: command:\033]11;#2c2c2c\007\033]10;#dcdcdc\007\033]12;#dcdcdc\007\033]4;0;#3f3f3f\007\033]4;1;#705050\007\033]4;2;#60b48a\007\033]4;3;#dfaf8f\007\033]4;4;#9ab8d7\007\033]4;5;#dc8cc3\007\033]4;6;#8cd0d3\007\033]4;7;#dcdcdc\007\033]4;8;#709080\007\033]4;9;#dca3a3\007\033]4;10;#72d5a3\007\033]4;11;#f0dfaf\007\033]4;12;#94bff3\007\033]4;13;#ec93d3\007\033]4;14;#93e0e3\007\033]4;15;#ffffff\007
URxvt*keysym.Control-Shift-F11: command:\033]11;#000000\007\033]10;#ffffff\007\033]12;#ffffff\007\033]4;0;#000000\007\033]4;1;#cc0000\007\033]4;2;#4e9a06\007\033]4;3;#c4a000\007\033]4;4;#3465a4\007\033]4;5;#75507b\007\033]4;6;#06989a\007\033]4;7;#d3d7cf\007\033]4;8;#555753\007\033]4;9;#ef2929\007\033]4;10;#8ae234\007\033]4;11;#fce94f\007\033]4;12;#729fcf\007\033]4;13;#ad7fa8\007\033]4;14;#34e2e2\007\033]4;15;#eeeeec\007
URxvt*keysym.Control-Shift-F12: command:\033]11;#000000\007\033]10;#a9a9a9\007\033]12;#a9a9a9\007\033]4;0;#000000\007\033]4;1;#cc0000\007\033]4;2;#00cc00\007\033]4;3;#cccc00\007\033]4;4;#0000cc\007\033]4;5;#cc00cc\007\033]4;6;#00cccc\007\033]4;7;#cccccc\007\033]4;8;#555555\007\033]4;9;#ff0000\007\033]4;10;#00ff00\007\033]4;11;#ffff00\007\033]4;12;#0000ff\007\033]4;13;#ff00ff\007\033]4;14;#00ffff\007\033]4;15;#ffffff\007
```

You can also take a look for another approach here: https://github.com/sos4nt/dynamic-colors

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an extension called [urxvt-theme](https://gitlab.com/trobador/urxvt-theme) that adds this functionality to rxvt-unicode (with a simple context menu) using X resources and dynamic colors.