# Different color schemes in URxvt?

Tags: colors, rxvt

I would like to be able to switch between a light and dark color scheme in an existing rxvt-unicode terminal window, in the same vein as switching profiles in gnome-terminal.

Would the best way to do this be to define the colors in a script outside of `.Xresources`?

Comment: Have you looked at the `xrdb` command?

Comment: @StephenHarris, very cool! I was not familiar with this command. Loading new settings through `xrdb` only seem to take effect once I open a new instance of `rxvt`, though.

Comment: Right; it modifies the resource database that's read when new processes start up.  It won't affect existing processes.  Sorry, it wasn't clear to me you wanted to modify existing windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch profiles just like gnome-terminal (or konsole), that is making changes to a running terminal.  `xrdb` will not do *that*.

If you want to change the foreground/background default colors, you can use the xterm *dynamic colors* escape sequences (which rxvt-unicode implements, as I noted in *[Urxvt: change background color on the fly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232881/urxvt-change-background-color-on-the-fly/295520#295520)*).

Comment: I am surprised I did not find that question before posting this one, as this is surely a duplicate. Just to clarify, the best way to switch colors would be to have a bash scripts with a `printf`  for each color by number?

Comment: yes, you can change the default foreground/background colors using a script.  "ANSI" colors override that.

Answer (score 5):

I added the following to my `~/.Xresources` file to change to colors on the fly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd> or <kbd>9</kbd>.

```
! change to red background
URxvt.keysym.C-7: command:\033]11;#ff0000\007

! change to light background
URxvt.keysym.C-8: command:\033]11;#ffffff\007

! change to dark gray background
URxvt.keysym.C-9: command:\033]11;#777777\007
```

If you want to set foreground and background color at the same time, just concatenate the commands (some colors are defined by names):

```
! change to red background
URxvt.keysym.C-7: command:\033]11;#ff0000\007\033]10;yellow\007
```

You can test your colors with a simple `echo` command, like this one:

```
echo -e '\033]11;#ff0000\007\033]10;yellow\007'   # changes to red background and yellow foreground
```

### Attention

I used code **11 for background** color and code **10 for foreground** color. The definitions for Urxvt cited by [Thomas Dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295520/31673) indicate to use **49 and 39** instead (which I tested and also work).